# ESP32 HTTP Client unable to connect to API URL

Tags: post, openai-api, arduino-esp32

I'm trying to make a POST to the Open AI API however my ESP32 is returning a failed to connect error. I cant figure out why

```cpp
    WiFiClient client;

      String lineEnd = "\n";
    String twoHyphens = "--";
    String boundary = String("*****") + String("AaB03x") + String("*****");
    String charset="UTF-8";
  
    const char *URL = "https://api.openai.com/v1/audio/transcriptions";
  

    Serial.println("Preparing to POST");

    if (client.connect(URL, 443)) { // Use port 443 for HTTPS
    Serial.println("Connected to server"); }
    else {
      Serial.println("Failed to connect");
    }
```

Failed to connect is printed every time. the URL is correct per the API definition and I am assuming 443 is the correct port for HTTPS. What could be causing it?

API Reference

https://platform.openai.com/docs/api-reference/audio/createTranscription?lang=curl

Expected "Conected to Server" to be printed but instead "Failed to connect" is printed

Tried ports 8080 and 443 same issue

Comment: Tried using WiFiClientSecure.h library and changed it to WiFiClientSecure client; but still not working.

Comment: If you are using WiFi Client, you are establishing a TCP connection, and you need to construct the HTTP yourself. If you are using HTTP1.0, then the request is `POST https://api.openai.com/v1/audio/transcriptions HTTP/1.0`. But if you are using HTTP1.1, it should be `POST /v1/audio/transcriptions HTTP/1.0 HTTP/1.1` and add the http header with `Host: api.openai.com` without the protocol info `https://`. Read [HTTP overview](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Overview) for better understanding of the http.

Comment: There is also [httpclient](https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/blob/master/libraries/HTTPClient/examples/BasicHttpsClient/BasicHttpsClient.ino) library which provide abstraction to cover all the http construction details with higher-level API and you can use the whole URL like "https://api.openai.com/v1/audio/transcriptions".

Comment: The `client.connect(URL, 443);` should not be the URL, but the name of the server, which is the first part of an URL after protocol, that is, in this case, `api.openai.com`.